# Debug a Symfony2 project with NetBeans and XDebug on Debian OS

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans, debian, xdebug

I usually use PhpStorm and the xdebug setup is easy and straightforward. But now I have to setup NetBeans to work with xdebug. I have the following configuration in the php.ini file:

```
[XDebug]

zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20131226/xdebug.so

xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
```

I also tried to put the configuration in the **xdebug.ini** file. But this does not changed anything.
How I have configured the netbeans IDE:

- I have checked the  **Stop at First Line** and **Show Debugger Console** from *Tools > Options > PHP > Debugging*
- I also right clicked on the project and opened the Propertes.
- I have set the **web** folder of the symfony project for a **Web Root** on the project in the **Sources** tab.
- I have setup the **app_dev.php** file as an index file in the **Run Configuration**.

I have put a breakpoint and started the debugger but It just doesn't want to stop. I believe my xdebug configuration is correct since I don't have any problems with the debugging in PhpStorm. Any suggestions on what I have missed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This configuration actually worked. I just had to restart NetBeans IDE. It bugs a little from time to time and needs a reboot to start working again.